# Apple iOS browsers randomly won't render HTML objects loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, ios, html, dom, safari

We have a problem that is only evident on iOS browsers (iOS 12.0) with our SPA application that uses HTML object tags to load widgets (HTML/CSS/JS files) through JavaScript onto the page.

The issue is an intermittent one when the page is loaded some of the widgets don't display/render on the screen, yet are loaded into the DOM and can be viewed/highlighted with full element properties in the Safari Web Inspector. but are “invisible” to their user. The problem will occur about 50% of the time if there are 4 widgets to load on a page, 2 typically won't display and it will be different widgets not displaying each time, with no detectable pattern.

The widget javascript load events run properly and there are no errors in the console. In the Safari Web Inspector, we can see some of the HTML elements from the non-rendering object are loaded at position 0,0 but their style is correct in the DOM (left and top set correctly, display: inline, etc.).

Here is the code that loads the widgets (the fragment is added to the DOM after all widgets are setup):

```
function loadWidget(myFrag, widgetName) {
    var widgetObj = document.createElement("object");
    widgetObj.data = "widgets/" + widgets[widgetName].type + ".html";        // location of widget
    widgetObj.className = "widget unselectable";
    widgetObj.id = widgetName;
    widgetObj.name = widgetName;
    myFrag.appendChild(widgetObj);                                        // build widgets onto fragment
    widgetObj.addEventListener("load", widgetLoaded, false);            // Run rest of widget initialisation after widget is in DOM
    widgetObj.addEventListener("error", badLoad, true);
}
```

Here is the code in the load event that configures the widget once loaded (we work around a Chrome bug that also affects Safari where the load event is fired twice for every object loaded):

```
function widgetLoaded(e) {
    var loadObj = e.target;
    if (loadObj === null) {
        // CHROME BUG: Events fire multiple times and error out early if widget file is missing so not loaded (but this still fires), force timeout
        return;
    }

    var widgetName = loadObj.id;
    // CHROME BUG: Workaround here is to just set the style to absolute so that the event will fire a second time and exit, then second time around run the entire widgetLoaded
    if ((parent.g.isChrome || parent.g.isSafari) && !widgets[widgetName].loaded) {
        widgets[widgetName].loaded = true;                          // CHROME: WidgetLoaded will get run twice due to bug, exit early first time.
        loadObj.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute");         // Force a fake style to get it to fire again (without loading all the other stuff) and run through second time around
        return;
    }

    var defView = loadObj.contentDocument.defaultView;            // Pointer to functions/objects inside widget DOM

    loadObj.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;overflow:scroll;left:" + myWidget.locX + "px;top:" + myWidget.locY + "px;z-index:" + zIndex);

    loadObj.width = myWidget.scaleX * defView.options.settings.iniWidth;            // Set the width and height of the widget <object> in dashboard DOM
    loadObj.height = myWidget.scaleY * defView.options.settings.iniHeight;
}
```

The code performs correctly in Chrome (Mac/Windows), IE and Safari (Mac), however, presents the random invisible loading issue in iOS Safari and also in iOS Chrome.

Any ideas what causes this and what the workaround could be?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or codepen with the issue visible ?

Comment: Its part of a more complex application so will take us a little while to set it up. Will post back here when ready

Comment: Perhaps the chrome bug doesn't exist on iOS safari and after `loadObj.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute"); return;` the function isn't called again.

Comment: We did test for that, it does exist in IoS safari and we have stepped through the debugger for this code and its working as intended. Its the randomness of not rendering objects on the screen 50% of the time that has us stumped.

Comment: did you contact apple for this bug? https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: No, not yet, was waiting to see if anyone here had some ideas before contacting Apple, and we will do shortly.

Comment: Have you tried `style.position = "absolute"` and such instead of `setAttribute("style", ...)`? Never saw `setAttribute` to set the style, as is pretty weird.

Comment: There have been issues with iOS browsers and CORS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454208/ios11-causing-cors-issues-in-all-mobile-browsers Can you check the logs to see if something has been blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We couldn't find the exact source of this issue after a lot of investigation and are fairly sure this is a webkit bug. However there is an acceptable workaround, which is to replace the object tag with an iframe tag, and it looks to be working exactly the same way (replace .data with .src) with a bonus it doesn't exhibit the chrome  bug where onload events are fired twice, so Chrome runs our app faster now.