# Reactjs axios return Network error if website opened with iPhone ios v12.4

Tags: reactjs, axios, laravel-5.8

I have issue that any part of my website loading content or sending data from api using axios to handle those requests, axios throw error of reactjs website opened with iPhone having ios version 12.4 .

[image]

This is example of one of axios http request i am using:-

```
 axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}book/${props.match.params.id}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: token() ? token() : "" },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setBook(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
        setNotFound(true);
      });
  }, []);
```

I am begin to suspect that the issue is from CORS, i am not much familiar with it and how it works, but what i've noticed in Chrome network monitor is on each request, the axios is send OPTION request before every each GET request.

### [image: OPTION Request]

[image]

I also used [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to monitor my network traffic of ios device stimulator, and noticed that only OPTION request is sent to the api backend:-

[image]

I am using Laravel 5.8 as a backend and Reactjs as Frontend
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",

Content of App\Http\Kernel file:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
        
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

Content of config/cors.php file :-

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS Options
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The allowed_methods and allowed_headers options are case-insensitive.
    |
    | You don't need to provide both allowed_origins and allowed_origins_patterns.
    | If one of the strings passed matches, it is considered a valid origin.
    |
    | If array('*') is provided to allowed_methods, allowed_origins or allowed_headers
    | all methods / origins / headers are allowed.
    |
    */

    /*
     * You can enable CORS for 1 or multiple paths.
     * Example: ['api/*']
     */
    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    /*
    * Matches the request method. `[*]` allows all methods.
    */
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin. `[*]` allows all origins. Wildcards can be used, eg `*.mydomain.com`
     */
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Patterns that can be used with `preg_match` to match the origin.
     */
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `[*]` allows all headers.
     */
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with these headers.
     */
    'exposed_headers' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age response header when > 0.
     */
    'max_age' => 0,

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
     */
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Should i disable CORS or changing the request header to fix this issue, how can i stop the OPTION request and is it necessary ?

Comment: Is it working normally in a web browser?

Comment: @kiranvj, Actullay the website is on production, we only get complains from users using ios 12.4, from my side i've tried (Chrome windows, Mac, Android) ,Firefox Mac, Safari Mac and Safari on iphone with IOS 13 all is working fine

Comment: If it works in other systems and fails only in iOS 12.4 , it should NOT be an issue with CORS. OPTIONS is a preflight request to check if server support cross browser request. Try enabling CORS in php and check again. https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: @kiranvj  Iam already using this library, please check my updated question.

Comment: Does this answer your question (i.e., try specifying the domain of the UI instead of * in the allowed origins header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454208/ios11-causing-cors-issues-in-all-mobile-browsers

Comment: Also note that CORS is implemented differently between different browsers, so you should be sure to test your application in all browsers you expect your customers to use. There can be differences in whether they accept a wildcard origin, or whether they send credentials with the OPTIONS request.

Comment: @rfestag referred to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004250/2873860 i have changed the wild card of allowed headers to Accept,Content-Type,Authorization and its working now. submit your answer here so i accept